# Can Oracle SQL Developer be made to reconnect as needed?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there an option in Oracle SQL Developer (I use version 4.1.5) to make it reconnect to the DB when needed?

For example, if I start an SQL script but the DB was disconnected, then it should reconnect with minimum hassle and execute the script instead of giving a `SQL Error: Closed Connection` message.

Note: I'm not interested in keep-alive (what most related questions discuss). If I don't use it today, then it is OK to disconnect. I just want it to reconnect next time I use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In at least SQL Developer version 20.2 this is implemented:

when running an SQL operation when the DB was disconnected after a while, the connection is restored and the operation is executed (there is also a dialog shown telling about the fact).

Comment: now we just need to get rid of that dialog...

Answer (score 2):

No.

Auto-connecting dropped connections sounds good in theory, but the 'auto' part is where the trouble begins.

I have a standing ER to add the reconnect button to the dropped connection ERROR message.

Comment: it's not a simple thing to implement, but it's on the list